# How to get Data from 2D json object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON respone array as follows

```
[
  {
    "productmeta_id": "13",
    "product_id": "2",
    "name": "CompanyName",
    "datatype": "text",
    "lenght": "100",
    "max_size": "100",
    "required": "0",
    "placedolder": "e.g Samsung",
    "product_description": "Ear Phones"
  },
  {
    "productmeta_id": "14",
    "product_id": "2",
    "name": "Model ",
    "datatype": "text",
    "lenght": "100",
    "max_size": "100",
    "required": "0",
    "placedolder": "e.g xyz",
    "product_description": "Ear Phones"
  },
  {
    "productmeta_id": "15",
    "product_id": "2",
    "name": "NETWORK Technology",
    "datatype": "text",
    "lenght": "100",
    "max_size": "100",
    "required": "0",
    "placedolder": "e.g Wireless/ Wired",
    "product_description": "Ear Phones"
  }
]
```

How can i Get name for each child array using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//parse it first
const arr = JSON.parse(jsonString);

//map names to the array
const names = arr.map(obj => obj.name);
```

Comment: np. Please consider selecting it as an accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

```
const names = (JSON.parse(response)).map(obj => obj.name);
```

Comment: why `[0]` ? You need an array.